# How to change position of svg on hover with a transition delay

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I'm trying to move svg icons in my navbar to the left on hovering, which I'm able to do so, but I need the element to move smoothly through something like this  `transition : all .5s;`
The issue is that svg tag doesn't accept transition property in css, so I tried to use the transition on the container, but that doesn't work, it just move instantly without transition effect.

**HTML** :

```
  <div id="sidenav-icon-section">
            <li>
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="/assets/images/home.svg" alt="home" onload="SVGInject(this)">
                </a>
          </li>
   </div>
```

I use the **SVGInject** library to transform my svg code in the browser, which results to this :

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64" xml:space="preserve" data-inject-url="http://localhost:4200/assets/images/home.svg" _ngcontent-c1="">

<polygon fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="32,3 2,33 11,33 11,63 23,63 23,47 39,47   39,63 51,63 51,33 62,33 "></polygon></svg>
```

Also I have another svg icon that has a **path** tag instead of **polygon**

**CSS** :

```
  #sidenav-icon-section {
    top: 25%;
    position: relative;

    li {
      position: relative;
      transition: all .5s;

      &:hover svg {
        left: 7%;
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried applying the transition to and the "left" attribute to path and polygon elements but nothing happens at that point, they don't even move.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the attribute `left` on an element which position is `static`. Try a negative margin instead. Also you are applying the transition to the wrong element.

---

```css
svg { transition: margin-left .5s }

li:hover svg {
 margin-left: -7px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="sidenav-icon-section">
  <li class="item">
    <a href="/">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64" xml:space="preserve" data-inject-url="http://localhost:4200/assets/images/home.svg"
        _ngcontent-c1="">

<polygon fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="32,3 2,33 11,33 11,63 23,63 23,47 39,47   39,63 51,63 51,33 62,33 "></polygon></svg>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the scss equivalent:

```
li {
  svg { transition: margin-left .5s; }
  &:hover svg {
    margin-left: -7px;
  }
}
```

Comment: @naspy971 I just reread you description and read that you're not able to apply
transition on an svg element. is there a reason for that?

Comment: I got issue yesterday when trying to apply this property to an svg tag, but still, I cant get your code to work in my case, really don't know why, the element still moves instantly.... :(

Comment: if you can replicate your problem in a snippet, codepen or whatever. We might be able to help you

Comment: Thanks anyway, I managed doing what I want by using  transform: translateX(7%); instead of left or marging/padding attributes